How to pause while loop every 60 minutes and call func for Token and use the new Token again in While Loop Header for continuing the loop
I am making API call request for a list of IDs one by one and appending it to a Dict. Finally saving output as JSON file. This code runs for more than 5 hours. Every 60 minutes the Bearer Token is getting expired. Is there a way where I can pause while loop every 60 minutes call the func() again to renew token and then pass the same inside header to continue the while loop? Or what is the best suggestion for this scenario? Please help.
import requests
import io
import hashlib
import time
import random
import json
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# --------------------  Generate Bearer Token ----------------------#

def myfun():   
    a = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    b = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    payload = {
        'key_id': a,
        'key_secret': b
    }
    response = requests.post('https://api.zdxcloud.net/v1/oauth/token',
                            headers={'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'accept' : 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps(payload))
    token = response.json()['token']
    return "Bearer"+" "+token
    
accesstoken = myfun()

# -------------------- DeviceID to List ----------------------#
import pandas as pd
import json
xl = pd.read_json("D:\Users.json")
deviceid = xl['id'].tolist()

# --------------------  Get Device Details ----------------------#


l = len(deviceid)
l = l-1
i = 0
id = deviceid[i]

st = datetime.now()
print(st)

data = {'mydata':[]}
while True:    
    id = deviceid[i]    
    url = "https://api.zdxcloud.net/v1/users/{0}".format(id)    
    payload={}
    headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': accesstoken
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, data=payload)
    results = response.json()        
    if i == 20000:
        break
    i = i + 1
    data['mydata'].append(results)
        
json_object = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
with open("D:\SysUserDetails.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)

et = datetime.now()
print(et)

exit()


you should check the response before working with it. if response.status_code != 200, then myfun() or something like this. hard to tell because I don't know the API documentation.
here you learn something about status codes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

You just need to check what time has passed
import time
...

last_token_update = time.time()
while True:
    now = time.time() 
    if now - last_token_update > 60*60:
       update_token()
       last_token_update = now 

    ...

Here we save the time before the start of the cycle, then check if the hour has passed and when it will pass, update the token and count down the hour again
